# Multiple databases connection in one web application - java

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I'm hosting a web application on Amazon web services on two different elastic beanstalk environments (i.e. two different RDS instances) one for test and another for production. each time I deploy the application I need to change the connection URL according to the environment.

Is there anything I can do to automate this process? a condition for checking the environment and connecting using the right URL or something?

Comment: or having a JNDI lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [Elastic Beanstalk environment variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html) to store the database connection URL, and any other environment specific settings. Your code would simply pull the value out of the environment variable, instead of having to do some sort of check.

Comment: Thank you very much that really helped! :)